# sort result of sql query by order of field in where clause of query

Tags: sql, sorting, sql-order-by

I want to sort the result of this query according to the contains of the query :

here it is :

`SELECT a from Frais a where a.libelle = 'FRET' or a.libelle = 'Douane' or a.libelle = 'Transitaire'`

I would like to have the records that have `FRET` first and `Douane` after and so on

```
order by libelle
```

doesn't resolve the problem it sort them according to alphabetic order asc or desc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT a from Frais a where a.libelle = 'FRET' or a.libelle = 'Douane' or a.libelle = 'Transitaire'
order by case a.libelle when 'FRET' then 0 when 'Douane' then 1 when 'Transitaire' then 2 end
```

Answer (score 4):

One option is to use a `CASE` statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Frais a 
WHERE a.libelle = 'FRET' 
   OR a.libelle = 'Douane' 
   OR a.libelle = 'Transitaire'
ORDER BY 
   CASE 
     WHEN a.libelle = 'FRET' THEN 1
     WHEN a.libelle = 'Douane' THEN 2
     WHEN a.libelle = 'Transitaire' THEN 3
   END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this by putting the values in a "temporary" table that has an explicit ordering:

```
select f.*
from frais f join
     (select 'FRET' as val, 1 as ord union all
      select 'Douane', 2 union all
      select 'Transitaire', 3
     ) vals
     on f.libelle = vals.val
order by vals.ord
```