# SQL, order by data entered

Tags: sql

I wasn't quite sure how to word this question. But if you imagine I have:

```
var contents = "5, 7, 1, 3, 4";
```

And I want to do a query:

```
SELECT id,name FROM db WHERE id in (contents);
```

I would get the following response **(a)**:

```
ID      NAME
1       ONE
3       THREE
4       FOUR
5       FIVE
7       SEVEN
```

But in reality, I want it to be ordered by the order of contents, i.e **(b)**:

```
ID      NAME
5       FIVE
7       SEVEN
1       ONE
3       THREE
4       FOUR
```

Is there anyway to have the resposne ordered as **b** and not **a**

Comment: Tag your question with the version of SQL that you are using.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26311454/330315) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4858828/330315) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16425430/330315)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ANSI SQL method uses a giant `case` expression:

```
SELECT id,name
FROM db
WHERE id in (contents)
ORDER BY (CASE id WHEN 5 THEN 1 WHEN 7 THEN 2 WHEN 1 THEN 3 WHEN 3 THEN 4 WHEN 4 THEN 5 END);
```

Answer (score 0):

With standard ANSI SQL you could join to a list of values that specify the sort order:

```
select t.*
from the_table t
  join (
    values 
      (5, 1),
      (7, 2), 
      (1, 3),
      (3, 4),
      (4, 5)
  ) as s (id, sort_order) on t.id = s.id
order by s.sort_order ;
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/UDW37167